# Geometric problem-differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I need to solve the following problem:

Consider the stright lines that pass through origin. Find the equation of the trayectories that intersect those straight lines at a constant angle w (use polar coordinates.)

Please excuse my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ a curve with the mentioned property. We have:

$$
\alpha(t)\cdot\alpha'(t)=\mbox{cte}\, ||\alpha(t)||\, ||\alpha'(t)||
$$

Since
$$
\alpha(t)=(r(t)\cos(t),r(t)\sin(t))
$$
we obtain the following equation:
$$
r(t)\cos(t)[\;-r(t)\sin(t)+r'(t)\cos(t)\;]+ r(t)\sin(t)[\; r(t)\cos(t)+r'(t)\sin(t)\;] =\\=\mbox{cte} \, r(t) \sqrt{r^2(t)+(r')^2(t)}
$$
Simplifying:
$$
r'(t)=\mbox{cte}\, \sqrt{r^2(t)+(r')^2(t)}
$$
Or equivantly
$$
(r'(t))^2(1-c^2)=r^2(t) 
$$
That is
$$
r'(t)=\lambda \,r(t) \;\; \lambda\in[-1,1]
$$
whose solution is
$$
r(t)=a\;e^{\lambda t}
$$

Kind of spirals. Here are some examples:

[image]
<sub>(source: [subefotos.com](https://thumbs.subefotos.com/168008318156faaff2e6730499d71606o.jpg))</sub>